# Exactly one root of $p_n$ between two consecutive roots of $p_{n+1}$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $p_n$ be a polynomial of exactly degree $n$, with positive leading coefficient, and suppose that it has $n$ simple real roots. Let $y_1<\dots <y_{n+1}$ be real (simple) roots of $p_{n+1}$. Assume that $p_n/p_{n+1}$ is decreasing in each interval free of zeros of $p_{n+1}$. Then we must have $\lim_{x\to y_i^{\pm}}p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)=\pm \infty$. Why can we conclude from this that $p_n$ has exactly one root between two consecutive roots of $p_{n+1}$?

I was thinking about using the Intermediate Value Theorem, but the interval, for example, $(y_1,y_2)$ is not closed. What to do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n$ and put $f=p_n/p_{n+1}$. You have observed that $\lim_{x\to y_i^{\pm}}f(x)=\pm \infty $.
Hence given $i$, there exists $a>y_i$ and $b<y_{i+1}$ such that $f(a)>0$ and $f(b)<0$. Furthermore, $a$ and $b$ can be chosen such that
\begin{align}
a-y_i&<\frac{y_{i+1}-y_i}{2}\, \\
y_{i+1}-b&<\frac{y_{i+1}-y_i}{2}\,.
\end{align}
Then $y_i<a<b<y_{i+1}$. By the intermediate value theorem, $f(r)=0$ for some $r\in(a,b)$.

Suppose, for contradiction, that $p_n$ has two distinct roots $r_1<r_2$ between $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$. Then $f(r_1)=f(r_2)=0$. Since $f$ is decreasing, it must be that $p_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in[r_1,r_2]$, which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate the existence part; how is it connected to the intermediate value theorem, when its condition has with the closed and bounded set to do with? What is our such set? Let's look at the set $(y_1,y_2)$. Is ours something like $[y_1+\frac{1}{k},y_2-\frac{1}{k}]$ for any $k$, because it's inside $(y_1,y_2)$, or how would you do it?

Comment: @James I've edited it. It's pretty much like what you said.

Answer (score 1):

If we allow $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ to have common zeros, the claim is false.

As a counterexample, if we define $p_0,p_1,p_2,...$ recursively by
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
p_0\!&=1\\[4pt]
p_{n+1}\!&=(x-n)p_n\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
then the hypothesis is satisfied but for all $n$, $p_n$ has no roots strictly between two consecutive roots of $p_{n+1}$.

So suppose we assume the additional condition that $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ have no common zeros.

Then the claim holds.

**Proof:**

Let $x_1 < \cdots < x_n$ be the roots of $p_n$.

Suppose $x_1 < y_1$.

On the interval $(-\infty,x_1)$, $p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)$ can't change sign, hence since one of $n,n+1$ is even and the other is odd, it follows that $p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)$ is negative on $(-\infty,x_1)$. But then since $x_1$ is a simple zero of $p_n$, the sign of  $p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)$ must change from negative to positive as $x$ crosses $x_1$ from left to right, so $p_n/p_{n+1}$ is not decreasing the interval $(-\infty,y_1)$, contrary to hypothesis.

Hence $x_1 > y_1$.

Similarly, suppose $x_n > y_{n+1}$.

On the interval $(x_n,\infty)$, $p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)$ can't change sign, hence $p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)$ is positive on $(x_n,\infty)$. But then since $x_n$ is a simple zero of $p_n$, the sign of $p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)$ must change from negative to positive as $x$ crosses $x_n$ from left to right, so $p_n/p_{n+1}$ is not decreasing on the interval $(y_{n+1},\infty)$, contrary to hypothesis.

Hence $x_n < y_{n+1}$.

Next suppose that $p_n$ has more than one root strictly between some two consecutive roots of $p_{n+1}$.

Thus suppose $a < b < c < d$, where $a,d$ are consecutive roots of $p_{n+1}$ and $b,c$ are consecutive roots of $p_n$.

Since $p_n/p_{n+1}$ is decreasing on $(a,d)$, and $b,c$ are simple zeros of $p_n$, it follows that $p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)$ changes from positive to negative both as $x$ crosses $b$ from left to right and as $x$ crosses $c$ from left to right. Thus $p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)$ is negative for $x$ slightly to the right of $b$ and is positive for $x$ slightly to the left of $c$. But $p_{n+1}$ doesn't change sign on $(b,c)$, hence $p_n$ must change sign on $(b,c)$, contradiction, since $b,c$ are consecutive roots of $p_n$.

Hence $p_n$ has at most one root strictly between any two consecutive roots of $p_{n+1}$.

Since $p_n$ has $n$ distinct roots, each of which lies in one of the $n$ intervals $(y_i,y_{i+1})$, and each interval $(y_i,y_{i+1})$ contains at most one root of $p_n$, it follows by the pigeon hole principle that each interval $(y_i,y_{i+1})$ contains exactly one root of $p_n$.

**Edit:**

Looking back at your question, I see that your idea was to approach the problem by using the fact (assuming $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ have no common zeros) that for each $y_i\in \{y_1,...,y_{n+1}\}$, we have
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to y_i^{\Large{-}}}p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)&\in\{\pm\infty\}\\[4pt]
\lim_{x\to y_i^{\Large{+}}}p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)&\in\{\pm\infty\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Here's an argument based on that approach . . .

Consider the interval $(y_i,y_{i+1})$.

We know
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to y_i^{\Large{+}}}p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)&\in\{\pm\infty\}\\[4pt]
\lim_{x\to y_{i+1}^{\Large{\;\;-}}}p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)&\in\{\pm\infty\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
but since $p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)$ is decreasing on $(y_i,y_{i+1})$, we must have
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to y_i^{\Large{+}}}p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)=+\infty\}\\[4pt]
\lim_{x\to y_{i+1}^{\Large{\;\;-}}}p_n(x)/p_{n+1}(x)=-\infty\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
hence by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $p_n$ has at least one root in $(y_i,y_{i+1})$.

Since $p_n$ has exactly $n$ roots, and at least one root in each of the $n$ intervals of the form $(y_i,y_{i+1})$, it follows that each of the intervals $(y_i,y_{i+1})$ contains exactly one root of $p_n$.